# Plotting fixed plot area

Tags: r, graphics, plot, area

I have simple question, how can I plot fixed height barplots, i.e. stretching the plot area only change margins not the bararea, like the following:

```
> A <- 4
> plot (A)

> barplot(A, col = "green4")
```

[image]

When I strech are, bar area also get increases.

[image]

Edits: I want to keep the box size constant even the plot gets stretched.

[image]

Comment: Once a plot has been rendered on screen (or on disk) you can't change that kind of thing without resorting to image editing software (Photoshop, Inkscape, etc.). If you want larger margins, you have to specify their size when you create the graph in R.

Comment: Thanks, I am not concerned about margins rather I am interested to produce plot with small bar size

Comment: In that case, I don't have the slightest idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Doing what joran said will make the plot smaller relative to the window like you want.  Even then, stretching the window will change the plot size....its what is does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by splitting the screen into multiple parts, you can achieve that partially:

```
split.screen(c(3,1))
A <- 4
barplot(A, col="green4")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to just expand the y axis. Look at `ylim`?

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is to fix your aspect ratio. This can be achieved using `asp`:

```
barplot(A, col = "green4", asp = 1)
```

See also this [post to R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/2900.html).

On a more philosophical note, when the height of the bar changes, there is no change in surface area. `barplot` only draws a sequence of bars, where the `x` axis is an ordinal (ordered categorical) variable which makes it impossible to calculate a surface area. The height of the bar is the only changing variable. I would recommend drawing these kinds of timeseries using a simple line plot.

So instead of:

```
a = runif(100)
b = 1:100
barplot(a)
```

[image]

use:

```
plot(b, a, type = "l")
```

[image]

or switch to my favorite plotting package, `ggplot2`:

```
require(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
qplot(b, a, geom = "line")
```

[image]